# SQL operator Like

Tags: sql

IN SQL can you use the like operator to see if the first  2 letters of a value match the last 2 letters in another value ?

If a have attribute year  and attribute phone number , i want to select these rows 
which match the description above  eg: year(19**96**) and phone number(**96**55771243);

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not in a reasonable way.  Most SQL engines support `left()` and `right()`, so you can do:

```
where right(year, 2) = left(phone_number, 2)
```

Databases that don't have other substring functions that do the same thing.

Using `like`, it would be something like:

```
where phone_number like right(year, 2) || '%'
```

Comment: ANSI SQL version: `where year like '%' || substring(phone_number from 1 for 2)`

Comment: @Hogan, seems like they aren't. (Did just search the SQL-2016 specification, and the only times LEFT and RIGHT are used, are in LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN.)

Comment: @jarlh -- interesting point.  On the other hand you won't be able to find an implementation of SQL that does not include it.

Comment: @Hogan, perhaps RDB?

Comment: @Hogan: Oracle isn't hard to find :-) Teradata didn't support it until 16.10 (and at least LEFT is not really needed).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Why should I search the MS SQL Server documentation?!? I came up with an ANSI SQL compliant version of your query (since the question has no dbms specified.) Hogan said LEFT/RIGHT are ANSI SQL functions, but they aren't, and neither supported by all dbms products.